# Replace content in http link from a text file in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am new in powershell and I have created the following script which it extracts what's between http:// and the next /, transform it and then replace the intial match:

```
$fileName = "myfile"
$newEnvironment = "NewEnvironment"
$config = Get-Content $fileName
$newConfig = $config | % { $_ -replace "http://www.site.de", "http://site.de.$newEnvironment" }
$newConfig = $newConfig | % { $_ -replace "http://www.site.com.tr", "http://site.com.tr.$newEnvironment" }
$newConfig = $newConfig | % { $_ -replace "http://www.site.fr", "http://site.fr.$newEnvironment" }
$newConfig = $newConfig | % { $_ -replace "http://www.site.pl", "http://site.pl.$newEnvironment" }
$newConfig = $newConfig | % { $_ -replace "http://www.site-1.be", "http://site-1.be.$newEnvironment" }
$newConfig = $newConfig | % { $_ -replace "http://www.site-1.nl", "http://site-1.nl.$newEnvironment" }
$newConfig = $newConfig | % { $_ -replace "http://www.site.it", "http://site.it.$newEnvironment" }
$newConfig | Set-Content $fileName
```

I'm trying to make it better, maybe using regex or something else but not using hard coded text.
Could anyone please help me with this ?

I was thinking something like:

```
$path = "myFile";
Get-Content $path | Foreach {$_ -replace "(?<=http://).+?(?=/.*)",".+?(?=/.*).newEnvironment"};
Set-Content $path;
```

But It did not work, even if it was setting the links in this way:

```
http://.+?(?=/.*).newEnvironment/asd/test.aspx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to

- remove the `"www."` part
- append the value of `$newEnvironment` to any URL

One way to do it would be to search for text that...

- is preceded by "http://" — `(?<=http://)`
- starts with "www." — `www\.`
- has characters other than space or slash, as group 1 — `([^/ ]+)`
- for safety, is not already followed by $newEnvironment — `(?!\.$newEnvironment)`

and replace it with "regex group 1" + "." + $newEnvironment:

```
$fileName = "myfile"
$newEnvironment = "NewEnvironment"

$pattern = "(?<=http://)www\.([^/ ]+)(?!\.$newEnvironment)"
$replacement = "`$1.$newEnvironment"

(Get-Content $path) -replace $pattern,$replacement | Set-Content $path
```

Powershell operators are generally happy with arrays. `Get-Content` will give you an array of lines and `-replace` will work on all of them. (Another practical property of `-replace` is that you can chain it: `"abc" -replace "a","A" -replace "b","B"` will work.)

This means there is no need to write a manual foreach loop. The only thing required is a pair of parentheses so `Get-Content` does not mistake `-replace` for a parameter.

`$1` is the back-reference to group 1, the backtick is PowerShell's escape character, because `$` itself has meaning in both Powershell and regex.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation! it worked fine after testing.